# pandas.DataFrame.apply() produces NaN when filtering with square brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"First_Column": [-2,-1,1,2,3]})
df['Second_Column']='Good'
df.loc[:, 'Second_Column']=df[df.First_Column>0]['Second_Column'].apply(lambda x: 'Bad')
```

When I run this I get `Bad` and `NaN` in the `Second_Column`, instead of `Good` and `Bad`. Why does `apply()` overwrite the values that didn't meet the criteria with `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `mask`

```
df.Second_Column=df.Second_Column.mask(df.First_Column>0,'Bad')
df
Out[441]: 
   First_Column Second_Column
0            -2          Good
1            -1          Good
2             1           Bad
3             2           Bad
4             3           Bad
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.First_Column>0,'Second_Column']='Bad'
df
Out[443]: 
   First_Column Second_Column
0            -2          Good
1            -1          Good
2             1           Bad
3             2           Bad
4             3           Bad
```

Or using `np.where` more straightforward

```
df['Second_Column']=np.where(df.First_Column>0,'Bad','Good')
df
Out[445]: 
   First_Column Second_Column
0            -2          Good
1            -1          Good
2             1           Bad
3             2           Bad
4             3           Bad
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle multiple conditions with `mask ()` or with any of the above approaches? I tried using `|` but it's not working.

Comment: @PrincyPrincy you should look at `np.select` :-)

Comment: I initially gave up too early and rushed to ask. After some more trial and error, it worked: `|` and presumably also `&` work just fine with `mask()`. Thanks.